# $_REQUEST empty on Vagrant

Tags: php, nginx, vagrant, phantomjs, php-7

I have a very strange issue with the php global variable $_REQUEST. When I render a page using PhantomJS, ajax query result in php with the $_REQUEST variable empty. This issue only appends when the PhantomJS script is run on vagrant. I have the same version of PhantomsJs (2.1.1) in local and in vagrant.

I verified the Nginx log, nothing is missing on the uri.
The php global variable $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] have /actions?params[...].

The php7 have all correct configuration about $_REQUEST :
`request_order = "GP"`

The nginx have the default configuration for query params :
`fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;`

Comment: Is `$_GET` populated? And are you certain you have modified the right php.ini file to set `request_order`?

Comment: $_GET and $_POST are empty and I verified the two php.ini (cli and fpm).

Comment: Did you check the output of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to confirm that PHP is actually using the one you modified? Sometimes another may be somewhere unexpected like /usr/local/etc or /opt or something.